# Can I drop SSH connections after five seconds?

Tags: security, ssh

I need to allow people to connect to my box, and then drop connections after a few seconds, regardless of whether the client is submitting data. Is this possible?

In addition, can I create a completely fake server? (i.e. only allow in-memory changes of files, to fool any attackers connecting into thinking that the server is real?)

Comment: These are called honeypots :)

Comment: There is plenty of good information on Security.SE about [setting up and running honeypots](http://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=honeypot).

Comment: you want a honeypot, but for the drop after 5 seconds, just make a script that sleeps for 5 seconds and put it as the user's shell in /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 6):

You are searching '[honeypots](https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=honeypot)'.

If you want to have fake SSH server, you can try [kippo](http://code.google.com/p/kippo/). It allow to you make a scenario for the attackers, they can upload some files to the special filesystem and so on. For setting kippo, you can see [this URL](http://bruteforce.gr/the-big-post-of-kippo-scripts-front-ends-bash-one-liners-and-sql-queries.html).

If you want to use fake servers for another services, see for example [this link.](http://blog.zeltser.com/post/1269495752/honeypots-for-malware-ssh-web-attacks) There is mentioned some other programs, which are runs as a honeypots and can emulate Windows (Dionaea), web services (Glastopf), and web browsers too (Jsunpack-n).